# Rails 3 Endless page, will_paginate with other AJAX on page

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, will-paginate

I am using twitter bootstrap and will_paginate. I have a laptop MVC with an index function which displays all of the laptops in the database. I also have a hidden form on the page which allows the user to input a price range and only laptops in that price range are showed, via an AJAX call. I am trying to follow the Railscast Episode #114 (revised), but the code conflicts with the price range stuff, and I'm not sure how to fix it. Code below:

**index.js.erb**

```
  $("#laptops").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@laptops)) %>");
  $("#laptops").append('<%= j render(@laptops) %>');
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@laptops) %>');
```

**laptops.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
  if $('.pagination').length
    $(window).scroll ->
      url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
      if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 100
        $('.pagination').text('Fetching more results...')
        $.getScript(url)
    $(window).scroll
```

**index.html.erb**

```
  <div id="hidden_form">
    <%= form_tag laptops_path, :method => :get, :remote => true do %>

    <%= hidden_field_tag "min_price", params[:min_price] %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "max_price", params[:max_price] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Get Laptops", class: "btn btn-primary", :name => nil %>

    <% end %>
  </div>

      <div class="laptops" id="laptops">
      <%= render @laptops %> <%#use :locals => ... to send other vars to partial%>
      </div>

      <%= will_paginate %>
```

**Laptops Controller:**

```
@laptops = Laptops.search(min,max).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
```